# A Puzzling Family

Tags: lateral-thinking, language

Ben is brother to Pat;
Daisy is sister to Tori;
Gail has two big brothers: Carl and Kyle, who look very similar.

They all stay close to town, don't like to venture out. But then there's the other side of the family...

Joe has a brother called Sean;
Vince has a sister called Fannie;
Zoe is sister to Sam.

These folks still live in town but also travel further up, where the air flows more freely (so they say).

It's an odd family, you'll see them out and about in couples but they never leave or come home with each other. I can tell you more about them (new hints every 24h), but maybe you already know what I'm talking about.

What links these sets of siblings and what divides the two groups?

Comment: Can u give me a hint?

Comment: @jingleBells: hint coming in 12 hours

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems:

> The initial letters of these names are in their siblings voiced and unvoiced. The first half the family are plosives, the other half fricatives. (I'm not sure this is how these terms are normally used, but I hope you catch my sense.) The hints are suggestive of the movement of air in sounding these consonants. But the biggest hint was the `language` tag.

Comment: Correct! But dammit, I was worried that the tag would be too big of a hint :(

Answer (score 1):

I think

> These are families of dog siblings. They go for walks with their owners ("you'll see them out and about in couples"), but not with each other ("but they never leave or come home with each other").

Comment: Nice try, but incorrect I'm afraid. See my most recent edit for a little hint.